# Javascript and jquery wont work for some reason

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Can someone help me? I wrote simple code in javascript and it wont work for some reason. I tried to figure out but i cant see why. I have downloaded jquery and it is all ok with it, also i tried only javascript code and still same problem. Browser is ok it load jquery and javascript on file i made earlier but doesnt load on this.Here is code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Proba</title>
        <script src="jquery-3.3.1.js">
            $('#btn').click(function f() {
                console.log(1);
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <button id="btn">Click</button>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: you cant use a `src` and an inline script in one `<script>` tag

Comment: i separated it but it still wont work

Comment: Separated it how? Also you cant bind an event before the element exists

Comment: i put <script src='jquery-3.3.1.min.js'></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">......</script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<head>
  <title>Proba</title>
</head>

<body>
  <button id="btn">Click</button>

  <script src="jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
  <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#btn").click(function(
        console.log(1);
       ))
      })
  </script>
</body>
```

Try like this :)

Comment: isto ovo sam kucao malopre i nije htelo ne znam koja fora.

Comment: I made the same thing in JSbin, check it there. https://jsbin.com/qajazuliju/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: Instead of local file, use jQuery CDN.

Answer (score 0):

You are binding your event handler, before the browser was able to parse your HTML. So `#btn` element is not in the DOM yet at this point.

Either wrap you code inside `document.ready` or move the script to the bottom of the `body` tag.

**1st Approach**

```
<head>
  <title>Proba</title>
  <script src="jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      $('#btn').click(function f() {
        console.log(1);
      });
    });

  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <button id="btn">Click</button>
</body>
```

**2nd Approach**

```
<head>
  <title>Proba</title>
  <script src="jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <button id="btn">Click</button>

  <script>
      $('#btn').click(function f() {
        console.log(1);
      });
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: i tried that earlier because i readed post on stackoverflow but it still wont work

Comment: It might have to do with the path. Try using jquery from cdn and see if it works. `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

Have you verified "jquery-3.3.1.js" really exists in the current directory? Try instead loading the script through a known host, like Google:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**EDITED**: Added working code. Note button checking must be done when document has finally loaded.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Proba</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){ 
   $("#btn").click(function() {
    console.log(2);
   });
  })
 </script>
</head>

<body>
 <button id="btn">Click</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i also put that link and same situation